# Unexplained removable volume

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian

I just finished a fresh reinstall of Debian jessie, which involved repartitioning and formatting of all LVs. However, upon booting, an unmounted "255 MB Volume" appeared, containing what appear to be installation files:

- grub, a folder that contains aesthetic objects like fonts and audio (notably, the audio is in a subfolder called "i386-pc" whereas the computer is amd64)
- lost+found, a hidden folder
- vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64, a DOS/Windows executable,
- System.map-3.16.0-4-amd64, a text file
- initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64, an archive
- config-3.16.0-4-amd64, an MPSub subtitles file

The USB drives I used to perform the install aren't 255 MB, and were removed long before I rebooted. lvscan lists only the LVs that I specified during setup. The location of the mysterious volume, /dev/sda1, implies that it's a partition of the hard drive, but I don't know why that would be the case. There was some free space left after partitioning, but it also was not 255 MB.

**EDIT**: this has been determined to be the boot partition. Why is this presented as removable and how do I hide it from the file manager?

Comment: Are you using LVM? Then it might be your `/boot`, although some of the files you mention don't make sense to me in that context.

Comment: I am using LVM, but it also doesn't make sense to me for that to be `/boot`. The computer was using LVM before I reinstalled, and this didn't happen.

Comment: Also, `/dev` lists sda, sda1, sda2, and sda5. sda5 is certainly the LVs, but I think `/boot` is probably sda2.

Comment: If you run `df`, that will show you what is mounted where and `sudo fdisk -l` will show you which partition is `Boot`.

Comment: Interesting, /dev/sda1 is indeed marked as `Boot`. I suppose the question is now how I hide it from desktop/file manager.

Also, /dev/sda2 is described as being from 501758 to 488396799 and /dev/sda5 is 501760 to 488396799 (2 sectors' difference). Is this normal?

Comment: Your `sda2` partition is an extended partition, that contains only one partition i.e. `sda5`. The command `sudo fdisk -l` will tell you. BTW, my set-up is the same (same starting sector, but different end sector). I am running `Ubuntu 14.04`. My boot partition doesn't show as a separate partition in file manager. I don't have a clue why it shows up in your file manager. Maybe `/etc/fstab` give you a hint.